# Combine Java logging with mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, functional-testing

I am going to explain the path that led me to asking this question on the chance that I am going about this wrong (the lack of Google answers to help me are a good indicator that this might be possible).

I am writing functional tests for my project's API endpoints. I want my tests to clean up after themselves, this is problematic because when I create a test user with a POST. There is no corresponding DELETE. So I created a log file that lists the IDs of all of the users created.

Now I am attempting to create a stored procedure or SQL event that reads the IDs from the log file and then removes them from the Database. This seems like it shouldn't be difficult, but I cannot find anything online that would let me even know how to start. The LOAD DATA INFILE commands I've seen all want me to create a table. Can't I just read each line from a file without needing to create a new table in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here. One is to read that log file with a Java program that makes it into a sequence of

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE userid=value-from-the-logfile
```

queries, and sends them to the database server.

Another is to load the log file into a temporary table with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, then issue this query:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM temptable)
```

Comment: Loading the data is a good solution. Though you'll need to make sure that your database account has permission to load files and create a temporary table. If that isn't a problem for you then it was the solution that worked better, at least for me. Thanks!